# pandas: groupby two columns and return diff for string column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, string, diff

I have a dataframe that looks like the following:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'First':  ['First value','Third value','Second value','First value','Third value','Second value','Third value','Second value','First value','Third value'],

'Second': ['A','B','A','A','C','B','C','B','B','D']}

 df = pd.DataFrame (data, columns = ['First','Second'])
```

I would like to group these two columns and return the corresponding value that is missing for each value in the First column in a separate column. so for example, the 'First value' from the First column does not have the B,C values from the second column and so on.

desired output:

```
First         unmatched value
First value   D,C
Second value  C,D
Third value   A
```

I have tried:

```
df.groupby('First')['Second'].diff()
```

But it does not work with strings and returns an error

Comment: the patter and desired output don't make sense to me.

Comment: I am looking for a method that would return what corresponding label is missing for each value in the first column. does that make sense?

Comment: "return what corresponding label is missing for each value" Is your output wrong then? Why is "B" missing for "First Value" and why isn't 'D" missing for "First Value"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `set`:

```
all_values = set(df["Second"])
#{'C', 'D', 'B', 'A'}

f = lambda x: all_values - set(x)

df.groupby("First")["Second"].apply(f)
#First
#First value     {C, D}
#Second value    {C, D}
#Third value        {A}
```